# FusionDirectory : Sending an email with postfix and force html content-type

Tags: debian, postfix

I'm not sure that's the way to do it but I'm trying to configure the "lost password recovery" on my FusionDirectory instance.

I managed ton configure postfix on my server to use our (external) SMTP server and send the email.
However, I receive it as plain text and I'm 100% sure that most of users won't copy/paste the link to make it work.

Is there a way to configure postfix to force `Content-Type: text/html` ?
Or am I missing something on FusionDirectory configuration ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the anwser from the developper of FusionDirectory.
This is not possible for the moment.
It might be added in a future version.